# apache2 crashes when trying to dynamically load python module

Tags: django, apache, azure, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I have a Django application, which has the following code init:

```
import importlib

def get_class(m):
    module_name, class_name = m.rsplit('.', 1)
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)       
    return getattr(module, class_name)
```

Whenever I make a request which requires a call of this function, in the error.log I see `child pid 27228 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache`, and request fails with error code 500.

The strange thing is that if I call that function from the command line, everything works well. Seems like mod_wsgi does not allow to dynamically load a python module.

I tried to do the following with all combinations:

1. Use virtual environment
2. Downloaded sources of python 3.6, compiled and installed it,
3. Recompiled the mod_wsgi for both default python 3.4.3 and new python
   3.6.

The error is always the same:

OS: Ubuntu Server 14.04
Apache: 2.4.7
Python: 3.4.3, 3.6.0

On my Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 everything works fine.
Apache is installed by `sudo apt-get install apache2`

in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
<Directory /my/django/app/appp>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-path=/my/django/app
WSGIProcessGroup myapp
WSGIScriptAlias / /my/django/app/app/wsgi.py
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

UPDATE:

I have downloaded and compiled apache2 and recompiled mod_wsgi. Still the same problem.

UPDATE 2:
Not sure if this will help, but the OS is on a Azure VM with Ubuntu Server 14.04

Comment: Does running on the command line mean `python manage.py runserver` or actually executing the code as a python command line application?

Comment: wwwuser can't access to /etc/.. directory.

Comment: means actually executing the code as a python command line application

Comment: "wwwuser can't access to /etc/.. directory." Do you mean www-data? Why does it need to?

Comment: I just tried with  `manage.py runserver`. Works well.

Comment: The problem is deeper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374775/apache2-mod-wsgi-crashes-when-importing-pyodbc